# System call Execlp()

Tags: linux

I have created my own shell in Linux.It takes path of file and command. It operates simple commands like grep ls etc. It uses execlp() system call.

e.g /bin/ls ls < this command executes properly.

ls < this command does not executes!

I just want to know what iam doing wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    while (true){
    char * input;
    string insert;
    char * token;
    char * parsed[5];
    int count=0;

    cout<<"My Shell $";
    getline(cin,insert);
    input= new char [insert.size()+1];
    strcpy(input, insert.c_str());

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        parsed[i]=NULL;

    token=strtok(input, " ");
    while (token!=NULL)
    {
        parsed[count] = new char[strlen(token) + 1];
        strcpy(parsed[count++],token);
        token=strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    delete input;
    delete token;


    pid_t mypid=fork();


    if (mypid==0)
    {

            execlp (parsed[0],parsed[1],parsed[2],parsed[3],parsed[4], (char*) NULL); 

    }
    else if (mypid>0)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }

    } //end of while
}
```

Comment: There's no point in just repeating [your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261678/execlp-system-call), you need to actually address the points which caused it to be closed. Show us exactly what you're trying to do (with code) and the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Hi Qandeel, you should edit your **On Hold** question to get it reopened, asking twice is not the way to go ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing one parameter to `execlp`; you need to specify the command to execute, and then all its arguments, including its first argument which is the command's name:

```
execlp(parsed[0], parsed[0], parsed[1], parsed[2], parsed[3], parsed[4], (char*) NULL);
```

The first `parsed[0]` is taken as `execlp`'s `path` parameter, and the second one is the first `arg`, which ends up as `argv[0]` inside the executed command.